# Counting number of subsets drawn from a set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a set $S=\{1..n\}$.

The number of ways of selecting half of the elements from $S$ is ${n \choose n/2}$.

My question is how to count the number of ways of selecting a different set on the second trial given the set from the first trial (with replacement).

I.e. draw a set $A$ of cardinality $n/2$ from $S$, and replace them. Draw another set $B$ of cardinality $n/2$ from $S$. How many possibilities are there for $B$ such that $A \ne B$?

I've thought of ${n \choose n/2}-1$ but that doesn't seem correct. I've also thought of ${n-1 \choose n/2}$ but that is counting something different also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first thought is fine.  As you say, there are ${n \choose n/2}$ subsets and you have excluded one of them.